# Rigorous method for showing this limit

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

> Prove the following limit; $$\lim_{x \to +\infty}\dfrac{\exp(x^2)}{10^{|x|}}$$

The limit of this is $=\infty$
But what is the best method to show this:
L'Hospital doesn't seem very helpful here.
i.e as $x\to\infty$ the function becomes $\dfrac{\exp(x^2)}{10^{x}}$.
This is a $\infty/\infty$ type limit; now differentiating $$\dfrac{2x\exp(x^2)}{\ln(10)10^x}$$ this is again a $\infty / \infty$ type limit differentiating again;
$$\dfrac{4x^2\exp(x^2)+2\exp(x^2)}{\ln(10)^210^x}$$ again this is a $\infty/\infty$ limit.

What is the best way to show that the limit is actually $+\infty$?

Comment: If you write $10^{\mid x\mid}=\exp\left(\mid x\mid\log 10\right)$, the limit is easily obtained.

Comment: Thank you very much, Ive got it now !

Answer (score 3):

Since $e^3\gt 20$, we have $e^{x^2}\gt 20^x$ if $x\ge 3$. So for $x\ge 3$, our fraction is $\gt 2^x$.

Comment: nothing could be better than this! +1 No LHR or some complicated limit formula.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that $a^b=e^{b\ln a}$, so $10^{|x|}=e^{|x|\ln 10}$. Thus,
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\dfrac{e^{x^2}}{10^{|x|}}=\exp\left(\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left(x^2-|x|\ln 10\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality, take $x>0$ so that we are trying to find $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)$ with $f(x) \equiv \frac{e^{x^2}}{10^x}$. Let $g(x) = \ln(f(x)$. Then 
$$
g(x) = x^2 - x \ln 10 
$$
Clearly $g(x)$ approaches infinity as $x\rightarrow\infty$.  (In fact, $\frac{g(x)}{x}$ also approaches infinity.)

So $\log \frac{e^{x^2}}{10^x}$ approaches infinity, hence $\frac{e^{x^2}}{10^x}$ also approaches infinity. And, a bit stronger of a statement can be made:
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \left(\frac{e^{x^2}}{10^x}\right)^{1/x} = \infty
$$